# Online classes for Undergrad and Graduate Statistics

Tags: references

I'm planning to strengthen my statistics this vacation, and I was planning to watch statistics classes online (preferably free...) during the break. There are so many classes online and I am just lost with all these options. Please do recommend to me some good ones.

(Please do note that I am an economics student)

Answer (score 3):

A very comprehensive introduction is this: https://www.coursera.org/specializations/statistics

You will learn R along with the statistics which will allow you to apply the things on data.

Comment: Thank you very much for this reference! It seems really comprehensive and from beginner level. :)

Answer (score 3):

[Joe Blitzstein's course](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/stat110/youtube) on probability for a pretty thorough introduction to the core of the discipline.

[David MacKay's course](http://videolectures.net/course_information_theory_pattern_recognition/) on information theory - this approach will be  pretty fresh for most people when they encounter it. [Has a free textbook accompanying it.]

Unless you already have a particular research question in mind, I'd stick close to the core because it's better preparation for having as-yet-unknown stats topics thrown at you. Also, get a book because I find I get lost if I'm not also working on some problems / reading. I never got on with 'learn through code' courses because I found they always confused the essential concepts with some language/implementation details.

Depending on your level of comfort with linear algebra, it may be worth following a course on that (e.g. [Strang's](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/index.htm)).

Comment: Wow I think these really the core of the discipline. And they are all free! Thank you very much!